# Symfony customised command stops after the first execution

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to create a customised command for my first time with Symfony.
This command should execute 3 commands in one go.

This is my command class

```
class DoctrineFullFixturesLoadCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('doctrine:full-fixtures:load')
            ->setDescription('...')
            ->addArgument('argument', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description')
            ->addOption('option', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Option description')
        ;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $argument = $input->getArgument('argument');

        if ($input->getOption('option')) {
            // ...
        }

        $arrCommands = [
            [
                'command' => 'doctrine:database:drop',
                '--force' => true
            ], [
                'command' => 'doctrine:database:create'
            ], [
                'command' => 'doctrine:schema:update',
                '--force' => true,
                '--complete' => true
            ]
        ];


        foreach ($arrCommands as $arrInput) {
            $this->getApplication()->run(
                new ArrayInput($arrInput),
                $output
            );
        }

        $output->writeln('Command result.');
    }
}
```

The issue occurs when the iteration starts.
It is actually executed only the first command in the line instead of all three.
It seems the iteration stops after executing the first command for some reason, which I don't understand, in fact the method at the end `$output->writeln`, isn't called at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the debug for the console to understand the problem.

Console commands run in the environment defined in the APP_ENV variable of the .env file, which is dev by default. It also reads the APP_DEBUG value to turn "debug" mode on or off (it defaults to 1, which is on).

To run the command in another environment or debug mode, edit the value of APP_ENV and APP_DEBUG.